# Convert GSM audio file to G.729

Tags: audio, sox, gsm

How can I convert GSM sound files to G.729 format? I've used Sox in the past for transcoding sound files, but have not been able to find a way to transcode to G.729. Using Sox, I have found a way to convert GSM to WAV.

Comment: ffmpeg says you can decode [GSM to G.729 BIT (but not G.729 RAW)](https://www.ffmpeg.org/general.html). Not sure if that helps you or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A free and easy way to convert proper sound files to G.729 is adding appropriate free G.729 codec binary to Asterisk and use 'convert' module.

You can follow these steps:

1. Install Asterisk
2. Follow [the instructions](http://www.blog.manhag.org/2010/05/installing-the-free-g729-codec-for-asterisk/) and install the free G.729 codec for Asterisk
3. And then issue this command to convert your 8k sampled gsm file to G.729:

> asterisk -rx "file convert /path/to/your/file/inputfilename.gsm /path/to/your/file/outputfilename.g729"